# Location of deployed liferay portlets

Tags: liferay

Where is defined destination of deployed portlets (wars)?
When I run command blade deploy, it deploys all portlets inside my liferay workspace and put their wars inside osgi/war folder. I want to have this wars in deploy folder, because I start this liferay application with docker and docker want to have them in /mnt/liferay/deploy.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy plugins to the runtime environment, you'll copy them into the ${liferay-home}/deploy directory (in your case, that's /mnt/liferay/deploy - where that is on the docker host, you'll have to figure out). The runtime environment will process your plugin (differing for WAR and JAR plugins) and move them to a location that you shouldn't have an eye on any more.

In order to deploy: Just copy them where they shall go. The directory will be empty again, once your plugin is deployed. The final destination location is irrelevant, as you can't change anything within it anyway (or: don't expect any live changes to have an effect on the running system).